How to find overlapping multi-dimensional ranges?
Suppose I am writing function find_overlapping_ranges to find overlapping ranges in a list of multi-dimensional ranges. Two multi-dimensional ranges overlap if they overlap in all dimensions.
from typing import List, Tuple
from dataclasses import dataclass

Interval = Tuple[float, float]  # Single interval with (min, max) bounds
Range = List[Interval]          # Multi-dimensional range

@dataclass
class Overlap:
  range1_index: int # Index of the first overlapping range in the list
  range2_index: int # Index of the second overlapping range 

def find_overlapping_ranges(ranges: List[Range]) -> List[Overlap]


The number of ranges is ~100K or more. Maybe it is worth noting that in the most case no overlap is expected.
The simplest approach is to check all pairs of ranges in the list, that results in a complexity O(n^2). Is there a more efficient algorithm to find overlapping multi-dimensional ranges ?

Why doesn't the naive approach seem tractable?  You have C(10000, 2) x 100 comparisons to do, which is ~5B, and the interval <--> interval comparison seems trivial. Have you tried it?

Actually, no. I just thought O(n^2) is not feasible for this data ... maybe you are right and it is not too bad.

BTW, what do you mean by "which is ~5B" ?

5 Billion comparisons, which is C(10000,2) x 100.  Realize (if I'm interpreting your problem correctly), you'll be producing a list with 49M elements in it, which is C(10000,2)

Got it, thanks. I should try ...

Two approaches come to mind: First is to sort the ranges, e.g. by their L2 norm, which should allow pruning the sets. The next one is a so-called octree, which divides the space into sections. For development, I'd restrict this to 2D, because that's something that can be drawn on paper. Depending on the input, you might be able to make use of some patterns even, but that's impossible to tell with the provided info.

BTW: If you just look at a single dimension of two ranges, you can quickly tell whether they overlap. If they don't overlap on a single dimension, they ranges don't overlap at all, which should make it quick to prune the input.

@UlrichEckhardt it isn't clear (from info provided...) how you could deduce that if you inspect 1 dimension of the 100 and determine it doesn't overlap that you could conclude that the remaining ones contain no overlap(s)?

Draw a rectangle (2D range). Now draw a second one that doesn't overlap in X direction, so that it still overlaps the first one. Just wondering, are you perhaps using the term range in a different way?

Yeah, I think OP needs to clarify what is meant by "overlap".  It seems from context that each dimension could overlap independently, where it says "overlapping intervals for each dimension", but that is ambiguous.  @Michael should clarify

@nocomment Thanks for the comment. I realized that my definition of overlapping was not correct. I need to check if there are overlapping ranges, i.e. the ranges overlapping in all dimensions.

I will delete the question and ask a new one.

I just thought the editing will create even bigger mess. I will try to edit the question.

@Michael Your edit says "all dimensions", but your comment says "at least one... dimension", which would imply any.

@beaker I realized that the correct definition is all dimensions after posting the comment. Unfortunately, I cannot edit the comment. I will probably delete it ...

This is a classic example where the Curse of Dimensionality means you can't do what you think in the natural way.
In one dimension, there exist many ways to solve this.
In two dimensions, the natural solution is to put the intervals into a Quadtree, and use that to look for intersections. But the performance drops substantially.
In three dimensions, you can instead go with an Octtree - the next dimension up from a quadtree. And performance gets worse still.
I would therefore sort them along a single dimension. Then only look at pairs that intersected in that dimension. And brute force the other 99 dimensions.
